# UIImage Object surprisingly returning null but not NSData

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

i have created a sqlite db.

and i have insert a few datas in my db..

```
UIImage * imagee=[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
NSData *mydata=[NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(imagee)];
const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

NSString *insertSQL=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into CONTACTS values(\"%@\",\"%@\")",@"Mathan",mydata];

NSLog(@"mydata %@",mydata);

sqlite3_stmt *addStatement;

const char *insert_stmt=[insertSQL UTF8String];
if (sqlite3_open(dbpath,&contactDB)==SQLITE_OK) {
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB,insert_stmt,-1,&addStatement,NULL);

    if (sqlite3_step(addStatement)==SQLITE_DONE) {

        sqlite3_bind_blob(addStatement,1, [mydata bytes], [mydata length], SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        NSLog(@"Data saved");

    }
    else{

        NSLog(@"Some Error occured");
    }

    sqlite3_close(contactDB);
}
else{
    NSLog(@"Failure");
}
```

have written some codes to retrive the data

```
sqlite3_stmt *statement;
if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK) {
    NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM contacts"];

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2( contactDB, [sql UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK) {
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            char *field1 = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0);
            NSString *field1Str = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String: field1];
            NSLog(@"UserName %@",field1Str);

            NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(statement, 1) length:sqlite3_column_bytes(statement, 1)];

            UIImage *newImage = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:data];

            NSLog(@"Image OBJ %@",newImage);
            NSLog(@"Image Data  %@",data);
        }
        sqlite3_close(contactDB);
    }
}

sqlite3_finalize(statement);
```

the problem is

in log, inserted `NSData` object and retrieved `NSData` objects are different (printing in log gives different stream)

moreover Image OBJ is printed null in log..

Have seen similar questions in stackoverflow. But nothing seems to help.

Comment: how did you solve it then ?

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(statement, 1) length:sqlite3_column_bytes(statement, 1)];
UIImage *newImage = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:data];
```

You are telling the compiler that the two objects are different, so when you print them, they will always be different. Guaranteed. Since they aren't the same object.

I'm not sure why newImage would display null though since you just allocated the object.

Comment: I think he's saying that the contents of the `NSData` object during insertion don't match the contents of the corresponding `NSData` being retrieved from the db (not that the `UIImage` and `NSData` don't match). I understand why you jumped to this conclusion (he's got that `NSLog` of the `UIImage` and the `NSData` right next to each other), but he's presumably comparing the `NSData` log output to the `NSLog` of the `NSData` in the prior snippet of code.

Answer (score 0):

You should perform `sqlite3_step` *after* `sqlite3_bind_blob`, not before. You're inserting before you tell it what to insert!

Checking results of `sqlite_prepare_v2` and `sqlite3_bind_blob` would be prudent, too.

I'd also suggest (unrelated to your question) `sqlite3_finalize` before you `sqlite3_close` in both snippets of code. And if you have an error, `sqlite3_errmsg` is a life saver, telling you precisely what went wrong, rather than guessing.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a major difference but you can try with this and also you can get the image length in console to detect image is properly responding from database or not:

```
const void *ptr = sqlite3_column_blob(stmt, 1);
int size = sqlite3_column_bytes(stmt, 1);
NSLog(@"%d",size);
data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:ptr length:size];
```